# How to match single character on bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a bash script to read an input from user and check whether the input matches a single character. Below is the code.

```
read letter

if [[ $letter  =~ ([a-zA-Z]) ]]
then
        echo correct
fi
```

When I input two characters it still says "correct", see below output:

```
$ sh tmp.sh 
aa
correct
```

how to write regular expression to matches exactly one character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you probably want to take different actions depending on the value, you may want to consider a simple case statement:

```
case $letter in [a-zA-Z]) echo correct;; *) : do nothing;; esac
```

This will make it easy change to things like

```
case $letter in
a) : do something for a;;
[b-m]) : do something else;;
[n-zA-Z) : ... ;;
* ) ... ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

**Your regex is not using anchors** hence it will match any input that has `[a-zA-Z]` but it will match anything that is greater than 1 in length.

Having said that you don't even need regex and can use **glob pattern** here which will match exactly one alphabet:

```
if [[ $letter == [a-zA-Z] ]]
then
   echo 'correct'
fi
```

If you must use regex then use:

```
if [[ $letter =~ ^[a-zA-Z]$ ]]
then
   echo 'correct'
fi
```